# Estoy teniendo problemas a la momento de importar los componentes a proyecto vue, que tiene un proxy reverso

Tags: vue.js, apache, proxy

Estoy tratando de incorporar un proxy reverso a mi proyecto vue, y tengo problemas a la hora de realizar la importacion de componetes, estos se solicitan a la pagina del proxy reverse, pero deben de solicitarse a la url del proyecto original, no a la proxy. con los componentes html ya logre solucionarlo con el modulo html_proxy, pero desconozcono como realizar esto con las importaciones de componentes en vue. esta es la configuracion de mi proxy revserso

```
ProxyPass /compilado/ http://localhost:6060/
<Location /compilado/>
    ProxyPassReverse /compilado/
    ProxyHTMLEnable On
    ProxyHTMLURLMap http://localhost:6060/ /compilado/
    ProxyHTMLExtended On
    ProxyHTMLURLMap / /compilado/
</Location>
```

como dije funciona con las importaciones de archivos html, pero no a la hora de realizar las importaciones de los componetes.

las importaciones de los html se solicitan de esta manera:
*http://localhost/compilado/spinner.css*

Pero mis componentes vue se estan solicitando de la siguiente forma
*http://localhost/src/scss/style.scss*

las importaciones de mis recuros en vue se realizan de la siguiente manera:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import {onBeforeMount, ref} from "vue";
import type {PrgReportePagosConvenioDto} from "@/entity/PrgReportePagosConvenioDto";
import axiosServices from "@/utils/axios";
import ReporteEncabezadoSinCodigo from "@/views/reportes/ReporteEncabezadoSinCodigo.vue";
</script>
```

una vez compilado pasan a ser texto plano, pero el html_proxy no esta añadiendo el prefijo que corresponde a estos...

agradeceria si alguien conociera una solucion

Comment: Pero, ese proyecto ya esta empaquetado para produccion???

Comment: si, ya se realizo el respectivo build, pero aun asi no logra realizar la peticion de recursos de manera adecuada.

Comment: es que eso es raro.. si ya hizo build, no deberia ir a buscar nada... quien esta yendo a buscar esos archivos???

Comment: la peticion de recursos se realiza en 2 etapas, la primera es la carga del spiner, y sus recursos los carga sin ningun incoveniente, pero cuando solicita los recursos de la pagina ya no logra cargarlos de manera adecuada, no les añade el prefijo /compilado, a la solicitud de estos mismo

Comment: estaran mal definidas las rutas de las cosas?? tendrias que mostrar un ejemplo...

Comment: acabo de editar la pregunta, con un ejemplo de como estoy realizando las importaciones de los componetes en el proyecto.

Comment: @Nick460, el `@` en los `import` [por defecto](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/1.3.1/template/build/webpack.base.conf.js#L40) `Webpack` los reemplaza por `"src"` (_ver [`resolve.alias`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias)_). ¿Será que tu `path` debería cambiar dependiendo del `env`?

Comment: si, era un problema del empaquetamiento a la hora de enviar los archivos, el proxy reverse no estaba realizando el desempaquetamiento, logre solucionarlo utiliando RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding pero aun hay algunos componentes que no estan cargando de manera correcta, el error lo causa el proxy reverse